# How powerful (literally) is a soul? Any physical reference points in scripture to calculate it?

Tags: scripture, atma, guru, science, conciousness

If a soul can control its own body it has to be able to exert a force and do work. This is an important point that often gets overlooked because of the very powerful illusion of unity in being all humans have (the subconscious means it is obviously false, but many people believe it nonetheless).

Anyway is a soul, especially a human soul ever in any scripture shown to perform an action that allows us to measure its power output? Has any guru explained or calculated the power of a human soul?

Comment: The soul is the seer it doesn't do any work

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Then it can't control its body and make any decision.

Comment: I think it's a valid question. How do we compare one soul to another, when we say he is a greater soul? His Atman is great - aren't all atmans great?